# Detect edges of parent container to change direction

Tags: jquery, detection, direction

I can't get this to work properly. It detects the top and left side perfectly fine, but I can't get it to detect the right edge and thereby apply the needed classes.

```
if( wps.o.position.autoChangeDirection && $(this).offset().top - wpsSpotBubble.outerHeight() - wps.o.position.spotBubbleDistance - 120 - $(document).scrollTop() < 0 ){
    $(this).addClass('wps-forcebottom');
    spotBubbleDirection = 'bottom'; 
    }
else if( wps.o.position.autoChangeDirection && $(this).offset().left - wpsSpotBubble.outerWidth() - wps.o.position.spotBubbleDistance - 140 - $(document).scrollLeft() < 0 ){
    $(this).addClass('wps-forceright');
    spotBubbleDirection = 'right';
}
else if( wps.o.position.autoChangeDirection && $(this).width() + $(this).offset().left + wpsSpotBubble.outerWidth() - wps.o.position.spotBubbleDistance + 100 > $(document).scrollLeft() + $(window).width() ){
    $(this).addClass('wps-forceleft');
    spotBubbleDirection = 'left';
}
```

I have tried searching a lot but my knowledge in jQuery is not good enough to make use of the info I have found.

Any help is appriciated!
//Oscar

Comment: Have you considered the jQuery UI 'position' plugin that allows elements to flip: http://jqueryui.com/position/